# BAD Record MAC error from the server

Tags: tls, gcm

I am working on ssl client because of some server update I was enabling the cipher TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256. While handshake with server I was facing Bad Record MAC Alert message from the server.

I was verified the time stamp and encryption status that are correct. That doesn't make any problem. I have no idea how to debug kindly give me the support how to debug.

I have got the gcm code from https://github.com/BrianGladman/modes/blob/master/gcm.h

I want to what are the possibilities for Bad Record MAC. How to debug and fix.

Comment: This question is better suited to StackOverflow. And probably can't be answered without seeing the source to your client. Something is wrong with the MAC, but solving the issue will require knowing how you create the MAC. It could be a bad packet getting received (about 1/4 million chance to slip by the TCP checksum), it could be you misusing your SSL library (OpenSSL needs different calls if used in a multi-threaded context, for a common one), or something else entirely.

Comment: Actually I am using mocana ssl that was not opensource. So I am not able to share the code, In this stack there is no support for AES128gcm so I was added that from the opensource.  At least I need support for how did I verify the AEAD cipher.

Comment: After refer RFC5246 they mention Bad Record MAC because of authentication error. The output of the gcm is cipher text+tag. Previously I am not concatenate the  tag with the cipher text, Now the issue was fixed.